# proof that $S=${$w\in R:xw=1$} is an infinite set in a ring $R$ with $xy=1,yx\neq1$

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring and let $x , y$ be elements of $R$ with $xy=1,yx\neq1$.
>
> Let $S$ be the set of all elements $w\in R$ such that $xw=1$.
>
> How I can proof that $S$ is an infinite set ,$($considering $w_n=y+(yx-1)x^n$ ,for $n=1,2,3,\cdots )$$??$

Comment: Is the general case correct? ((Any ring $R$ containing some elements $x,y$ such that $xy=1$ and $yx\neq1$ must be infinite,In other word: If $R$ is finite and $xy=1$ then $yx=1$ ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the above suggests we consider $xw_n$, for any given $n$, right?

Computing...

$$
xw_n = xy + xyx^{n+1} - x^{n+1} = 1 + x^{n+1} - x^{n+1} = 1
$$

which holds true for any $n > 0$.

Next, you need simply show that $n$ and $m$ distinct implies $w_n$ does not equal $w_m$ and you're done (Hint: you'll probably use the other fact that we haven't used yet).

Answer (score 1):

Note $xw_n = 1$ so you need to show that the $w_n$ give infinitely many different elements, that is, $w_n = w_m$ implies $n = m$.

**Hint:** Assume $w_n = w_m$ and $n \neq m$.  Show that $x$ has a left inverse, it also has a right inverse ($y$).  Finally, show that if an element has a left and a right inverse then these two elements are equal.  But this contradicts $yx \neq 1$ so our assumption that $n \neq m$ was incorrect.

Comment: your hint is very usfull.. thank u so much